# Twitter ios ( for < ios5) library for authentication

Tags: ios, twitter

What is the best Twitter  library for ios platform (for versions < iOS 5) for authentication.

I have an app which allows users to "Connect using twitter".

Answer (score 0):

[MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) is the most well known and most used pre iOS 5 engine, but others exist. Github report [274 repos](https://github.com/search?q=twitter&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C) with a twitter search crossed with Objective-C, so if `MGTwitterEngine` is not your cup-o-tea, there are plenty of other resources available to you.